# Multiple left joins in a single statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple queries that I'm trying to combine into a single one with no luck. I'm using left join on the same table twice with a different field and that sounds wrong.

```
SELECT a.* 
     , b.CODE_DESCRIPTION AS highest_grade 
  FROM BBOP.EP_MAIN_FACT a 
       LEFT JOIN BBOP.EP_CODE_WORK b 
              ON a.HIGHESTGRADE_CA = b.code
             AND code_type LIKE 'High%'
       LEFT JOIN BBOP.EP_CODE_WORK ab 
              ON a.Goal_Steps = ab.code
             AND code_type LIKE 'Goal%'
 WHERE plan_date BETWEEN '01-mar-2019' AND '31-may-2019';
```

--  ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

Here are the 2 queries, separately they produce results with no problems.

-- Highest Grade

```
SELECT a.* 
     , b.CODE_DESCRIPTION AS highest_grade_desc 
  FROM BBOP.EP_MAIN_FACT a 
       LEFT JOIN BBOP.EP_CODE_WORK b 
              ON a.HIGHESTGRADE_CA = b.code
 WHERE plan_date BETWEEN '01-mar-2019' AND '31-may-2019'
   AND code_type LIKE 'High%';
```

-- Goals

```
SELECT a.* 
     , b.CODE_DESCRIPTION AS Goal 
  FROM BBOP.EP_MAIN_FACT a 
       LEFT JOIN BBOP.EP_CODE_WORK b 
              ON a.Goal_Steps = b.code
 WHERE plan_date BETWEEN '01-mar-2019' AND '31-may-2019'
   AND code_type LIKE 'Goal%';
```

Comment: I re-tagged your question with `oracle` as the error message clearly indicates you are using Oracle, not Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah its Orcale sorry, have both open at the moment so I mixed them up.

Comment: Use alias name of the table before `code_type` and `plan_date`  on line# 4,6 and 7 in your first query

Comment: The solution to the problem (ORA-00918) is to properly prefix every column with the table name it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select mf.*, coalesce(cwh.CODE_DESCRIPTION, cwg.CODE_DESCRIPTION) as highest_grade 
from BBOP.EP_MAIN_FACT mf left join
     BBOP.EP_CODE_WORK cwh
     on mf.HIGHESTGRADE_CA = cwh.code and
        cwh.code_type like 'High%' left join
     BBOP.EP_CODE_WORK cwg
     on mf.Goal_Steps = cwg.code and
        cwg.code_type like 'Goal%'
where mf.plan_date >= date '2019-03-01' and
      mf.plan_date < date '2019-06-01';
```

Notes:

- In a query that references multiple tables, qualify *all* column references.  This is the root of your problem.  You have "bare" column references in the `on` clauses.
- Use meaningful table aliases, rather than arbitrary letters.
- The `coalesce()` chooses the values based on the priority order of the joins.
- Oracle supports the `date` keyword to introduce date literals.  This is safer than relying on default formats which may change on a given server.
- `between` is dangerous for dates, particularly in Oracle where the `date` type always has a time component.  Inequalities capture the logic.

Answer (score 0):

As someone has already stated in comments, the columns plan_date and code_type need to have table alias specified in their usage.

I am guessing at least one of these columns is in BBOP.EP_CODE_WORK table and hence the table alias needs to be specified while referencing these colums.

Regards
Akash